# Monodevelop's text editor

Tags: mono, monodevelop, rich-text-editor

There are several articles that instruct how to use avalonedit of sharpdevelop (avalonedit is the editor of sharpdevelop). Is there any article out there that explains how to use monodevelop's text editor?  Also, what's the name of that editor; does it have a name?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A while ago the previous text editor was replaced by [Mono.TextEditor](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/tree/master/main/src/core/Mono.Texteditor). There's not much documentation on it, or articles about it, but you could look at how it is integrated into MonoDevelop.

Answer (score 1):

Monodevelop was originally a [port](http://monodevelop.com/FAQ) of Sharpdevelop. You can find a lot of tips on monodevelop [here](http://mjhutchinson.com/tags/monodevelop_tips).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I think it does not quite answer my question. The website only talks about how to use mono develop, rather than how to use the code/components of mono develop.

Comment: I am more interested in using its API than code. I am thinking of turning it into a Latex editor.